# Setting up DHCP

Tags: dhcp

I've been playing around with Packet Tracer setting up DHCP on a router, in which I have no issues. But being curious has me stump now. I have a LAN consisting of two clients a server and a switch. Can I configure DHCP using the server without any router present in my network topology? Can I use a default gateway other than 0.0.0.0 if I'm not using a router? Is there any scenario where a router is need if DHCP is being ran off a server in the topology discussed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I configure DHCP using the server without any router present in my
>   network topology?

You don't need a router to run DHCP.  In fact, it is much more common to run DHCP on a server than a router.

> Can I use a default gateway other than 0.0.0.0 if I'm not using a
>   router?

If you have no routers in your network, then you don't need a default gateway -- there's nowhere to route to.

> Is there any scenario where a router is need if DHCP is being ran off
>   a server in the topology discussed above.

You need a router if you have to route between networks.  That is completely independent of the use of DHCP.